# error running expo with react-native gives Application main has not been registered error

Tags: expo, react-native

I'm getting an odd error now, and this seems to happen no matter what build I deploy. I can switch to a different set of tutorial directories or other folders, run npm start, and on the Expo device on my Android I'll still get this error.

It seems to not matter whether I run Expo SDK 33 or one higher, like 34 or 37. Oddly, I do have a build that sort of works on a different LAN IP. This is odd, because I don't even think I have another build running and this shouldn't pull up, but it does. I'll attach a screen shot here, but I'm really confused as to why this is happening. I can't find any reference (per the screen shot) where the StyleSheet method is missing.
[image]

I am running Expo34.0.4 in this build and using the following react-native build reference -
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.0.tar.gz",

Should I install a specific (different) version of both Expo and React-Native?

This had been working for a while and then suddenly started giving this error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the compatible version for your SDK? Use react-native from https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.2.tar.gz for Expo SDK 34.

[Each Expo SDK version depends on a React Native version.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/#each-expo-sdk-version-depends-on-a)

Comment: Ok, so then just copy and paste this line into the package.json dependency list and rerun an npm install for it? Or just run npm start with it?

Comment: Delete your node_modules folder and run npm install. If the error still exsists, run 
    expo doctor

Comment: Well, I manually installed expo@34.0.1, react--native@0.59.8, reinstalled two expo installation react-native plugins and I still get the above error. I'm not sure what else to do or how to troubleshoot the above. I would think a slug is mentioned in an old app,json file but I can't even find that! I will  try deleting the node mods and run npm install. Is the expo doctor an npm command? or just "expo doctor" is the cmd?

Comment: I deleted all the node_modules and ran npm start again...got the same darn error. Then ran expo doctor as instructed. results below: C:\Users\user23\projects\practice-shop-02-basic-nav-setup>expo doctor
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                   anager e latest version      │
│                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Didn't find any issues with your project!

Comment: Ok, I had to clear all of the expo cache and data and got rid of that issue...now I'm getting one with regard to the react-navigation-stack install.Unable to resolve "react-native-safe-area-context" from "node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\vendor\views\Stack\StackView.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7033